# StreamWriter через Linq

Tags: c#

У меня есть массив файлов, для которых нужно производить запись/удаление текста.

```
string[] arrayMass = new string[] { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("people.txt", true))
{
   writer.WriteLine("");
}
```

Как мне вместо `"people.txt"` подставить массив `arrayMass` не используя цикл `for` и `foreach`, а сделать через LINQ?

Comment: один вопрос: зачем?

Comment: `foreach` подходит идеально, почему нужно без него?

Comment: кроме того, максимум что можно сделать с помощью LINQ в этой ситуации, - это использовать тот же `foreach`, только завуалированно: `arrayMass.ToList().ForEach(filename => { ... })`

Comment: Как насчёт Reactive Extensions (RX)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем вас цикл `foreach` не устраивает? И нет, в Linq нету того что вам нужно. Последняя буква LINQ - "Q" означает "Query", то есть "запрос", а запрос должен что-то возвращать. Ваш код не возвращает ничего, следовательно это не "запрос".

Если вы имеете в виду под Linq паттерн Fluent Interface с делегатами, то у `List<T>` есть метод `.ForEach`, который кстати не Fluent, потому что ничего не возвращает `void`. В случае с массивом, вы можете написать метод расширения сами.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
     public static void ForEach<T>(this T[] array, Action<T> action)
     {
         foreach (T item in array)
         {
             action(item);
         }
     }
}
```

Это точный аналог того что есть у `List<T>`.

И вот так использовать.

```
string[] arrayMass = new string[] { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
arrayMass.ForEach(x =>
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(x, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("");
    }
});
```

Только я в этом никаких преимуществ перед обычным `foreach` циклом не вижу. А вы?

---

Кстати, если вам нужно создать пустой файл и ничего туда не писать, это можно сделать так `File.Create(path).Close();`.

Comment: спасибо! А если файлы находятся в определённой папке, как мне совместить путь к файлам с x => ?

Comment: @ZidoX `Path.Combine(dir, x)`