# Одновременный запуск асинхронных методов

Tags: c#, асинхронность, task

Имеет смысл выделять асинхронные методы в отдельные задачи, с целью одновременного начала работы всех методов и ожидание самого последнего перед продолжением работы основного потока?

Например 3 асинхронные задачи:

```
var users = await _db.Users.ToListAsync();
var additionalInfo = await _client_api.GetAsync(request_to_additional_api);
var weather = await _client.GetAsync(request_to_weather_api);

users.ToList().ForEach(u=>u.AdditionalInfo = additionalInfo.Where(ai=>ai.UserId == u.Id));
var resultDataViewModel = new ResultDataViewModel{
    Users = users ,
    Weather = weather 
};
```

Имеет смысл создать для них 3 отдельных таска?

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[3];
IEnumerable<User> users = null;
AdditionalInfo additionalInfo =null;
Weather weather =null;
tasks[0] = Task.Run(async=> {
    users = await _db.Users.ToListAsync();
});
tasks[1] = Task.Run(async=> {
    additionalInfo = await _client_api.GetAsync(request_to_additional_api);
});
tasks[2] = Task.Run(async=> {
    weather = await _client.GetAsync(request_to_weather_api);
});
Task.WaitAll(tasks);

users.ToList().ForEach(u=>u.AdditionalInfo = additionalInfo.Where(ai=>ai.UserId == u.Id));
var resultDataViewModel = new ResultDataViewModel{
    Users = users ,
    Weather = weather 
};
```

Если бы методы были синхронными, то однозначно стоило бы использовать 3 таска. А стоит ли применять подобную конструкцию из тасков для асинхронных методов?

Comment: `.ToList().ForEach` это жесть, чем вам обычный `foreach` цикл не угодил? Зачем спавнить дубликат коллекции ради синтаксиса? Если конечно все настолько плохо, то можно сделать [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430415/373567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.Run` в данном случае совсем не нужен.

```
var usersTask = _db.Users.ToListAsync();
var infoTask = _client_api.GetAsync(request_to_additional_api);
var weatherTask = _client.GetAsync(request_to_weather_api);

var users = await usersTask;
var additionalInfo = await infoTask;

users.ForEach(u => u.AdditionalInfo = additionalInfo.Where(ai => ai.UserId == u.Id));

var weather = await weatherTask;

var resultDataViewModel = new ResultDataViewModel
{
    Users = users,
    Weather = weather
};
```

Запускаем три задачи без ожидания. Они все начинают выполняться, запросы уходят в БД и API.

В методе `ForEach` нужны значения двух завершённых задачи, поэтому перед вызовом этого метода ожидаем их.

Ожидание третьей задачи можно выполнить после `ForEach`. Таким образом, даже если она окажется долгой, то будет выполняться одновременно с `ForEach`.